# AVPlayer video still playing after segue to next view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, video, avplayer

I'm currently looping my mp4 video with no playback controls, kind of like a gif but with sound. But I do not know why when I segue to the next view controller, the video is still playing. Does anybody know the simplest method to resolve this issue?

ViewController

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
fileprivate var playerObserver: Any?


class ScoreController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let returnValue: Int = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "userScore")
        label.text = "Your Score: \(returnValue)/30"

        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Innie-Kiss", ofType:"mp4")
            let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path!))
            let resetPlayer = {
                player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
                player.play()
            }
            playerObserver = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem, queue: nil) { notification in resetPlayer() }
            let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
            controller.player = player
            controller.showsPlaybackControls = false
            self.addChildViewController(controller)
            let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
            let videoFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 130, width: screenSize.width, height: (screenSize.height - 130) / 2)
            controller.view.frame = videoFrame
            self.view.addSubview(controller.view)
            player.play()
        } catch {
        }
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    }
    fileprivate var player: AVPlayer? {
        didSet { player?.play() }
    }
    deinit {
        guard let observer = playerObserver else { return }
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer)
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()  
    }
    @IBAction func doneButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "done", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: stop the player before moving to next view controller.

Comment: and what is the appropriate code to do that?

Comment: try to use this :   AVAudioSession.setActive(false, with: AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptions.notifyOthersOnDeactivation)

Comment: paste this code on my button action right

Comment: yes, when u are moving to next vc, execute this first.

Comment: sadly, this error came out https://ibb.co/d89YWS

Comment: @Shivam Tripathi bro I really need your in this, really appreciate it a lot if I can solve this

Comment: what if my AVPlayer is inside a tableview cell. How to stop the playback when i just popped to previous viewcontroller

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In viewWillDisapper() or button action for segue do this :

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
```

Also move this from viewDidLoad() to some function like :

```
 var player: AVPlayer?

 func audioPlayer(){
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        let path                         = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Innie-Kiss", ofType:"mp4")
        player                           = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path!))
        let resetPlayer                  = {
            self.player?.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
            self.player?.play()
        }
        playerObserver                   = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player?.currentItem, queue: nil) { notification in resetPlayer() }
        let controller                   = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player                = player
        controller.showsPlaybackControls = false
        self.addChildViewController(controller)
        let screenSize                   = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
        let videoFrame                   = CGRect(x: 0, y: 130, width: screenSize.width, height: (screenSize.height - 130) / 2)
        controller.view.frame            = videoFrame
        self.view.addSubview(controller.view)
        player?.play()
    } catch {
    }
}
```

and make player object a global variable. `var player = AVPlayer?` and in `viewWillDisappear` make it `nil`.

So your viewWillDisappear should look like this :

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
     NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    if player != nil{
        player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
        player = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: strange... i did exactly what u did and the audio still loops :/

Comment: make AVPlayerViewController object as global too and release that too. Can you also show what you updated ?

Comment: and also stop player before making it nil.

Comment: ok i tried setting my AVPlayerViewController to be global too, but an error occured, you can at look this image for more info and the codes i did - https://ibb.co/dODigS 
https://ibb.co/jAfkvn

Comment: Also, swift doesn't allow player.stop() so i can't do that

Comment: And don't make AVPlayerViewController global, it should work without it. But just for you info, it is crashing because you are not initializing it before using it.

Comment: Glad it helped, happy coding!

Comment: what if my AVPlayer is inside a tableview cell. How to stop the playback when i just popped to previous viewcontroller

Comment: @SharadChauhan i have a collection view inside tableview cell. Through the link you suggested i wasn't able to do it..any more suggestions??

Comment: @TheTravloper Without seeing your code I can't. You can ask another question for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

    }
```

This may be helpful to you if you are switching windows; as you perform a segue, you will execute the function included in curly brackets automatically. I'm rubbish with AV, but some of the other's code suggested to turn off the function may work here if it isn't working in the IBAction.

I'm not great with Xcode though, so mileage will probably vary.

Comment: I did try this, but to no avail. It stills hear-able even if I go the next view controller :/

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and fixed it by adding this line before setting player to nil:

[self.player pause];

here is my viewWillDisapear:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                                  object:self.player];
    [self.player removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"rate"];
    [self.player removeTimeObserver:self.playerObserver];
    self.playerObserver = nil;
    [self.player pause];
    self.player = nil;
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:@(UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) forKey:@"orientation"];
    [UINavigationController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];
    [StayfilmApp restrictOrientation:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ScoreController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
    var player: AVPlayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let returnValue: Int = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "userScore")
        label.text = "Your Score: \(returnValue)/30"

        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Innie-Kiss", ofType:"mp4")
            player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path!))
            let resetPlayer = {
                player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
                player.play()
            }
            playerObserver = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem, queue: nil) { notification in resetPlayer() }
            let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
            controller.player = player
            controller.showsPlaybackControls = false
            self.addChildViewController(controller)
            let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
            let videoFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 130, width: screenSize.width, height: (screenSize.height - 130) / 2)
            controller.view.frame = videoFrame
            self.view.addSubview(controller.view)
            player.play()
        } catch {
        }
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        player.pause()
    }
    fileprivate var player: AVPlayer? {
        didSet { player?.play() }
    }
    deinit {
        guard let observer = playerObserver else { return }
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer)
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()  
    }
    @IBAction func doneButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "done", sender: self)
    }
}
```

notable changes:

```
var player: AVPlayer?
```

and also

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    player?.pause()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when I used segue to go to the next ViewController, then I used present code with swift by using this code

```
     @IBAction func next(_ sender: Any) {


            let vc = self .storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"ViewControllerAA") as! ViewControllerAA
                   self.present(vc,animated: true,completion: nil)

}
```

but the problem didn't solve , then I used this code to go to the next VC and my problem solved and the background sound of the video stoped, and the code is this below

```
 @IBAction func next(_ sender: Any) {


     if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerAA") as? ViewControllerAA {
         let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
         appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = vc
      }





    }
```